# Android, opengl, move glsurfaceview

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I have created `glsurfaceview` in xml file, I'd like to change X,Y of this `glsurfaceView` when the button is pressed.
I have `onSurfaceChanged()` method and there are x,y variables.
can I call this method for chane `glsurfaceview` position?
if I can, how can I do it, or how can change position?

Comment: Maybe putting some code of what have you tried, might help.

Answer (score 1):

> I have onSurfaceChanged() method and there are x,y variables. can I
>   call this method for chane glsurfaceview position?

No, you can't, because `onSurfaceChanged (GL10 gl, int width, int height)` serves as an event. It is called by the OpenGL ES subsystem when your surface size has **already** changed. Therefore, it is for overriding and performing certain typical operations ([as detailed here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.Renderer.html)) when the size of your surface has already changed.

Since `GLSurfaceView` is a `SurfaceView` descendant and is part of the `View` hierachy, you can use the usual positioning methods (such as [setX()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setX%28float%29)) to set its position (but *don't forget* about screen- and density-independence that you should ensure in your Android applications).

As a side note: I don't know your application architecture and details, but when there is a need to re-position a `GLSurfaceView`, then usually there is an equivalent solution/workaround to the same problem that doesn't require repositioning.